# Quais as diferenças entre um DataTable e um DataReader para consultas ao MySQL no C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datatable, ado.net

Eu estou criando um projeto em C# com MySQL, meu conector segue o padrão Singleton e uso MySqlDataReader para recuperar os dados da tabela e popular um List até ai tudo bem.

Meu problema começou quando tive que recuperar os dados de uma tabela antes de terminar de recuperar os dados de outra. O MySqlDataReader dava o erro "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first". 
Lendo na net vi que esse erro ocorre no MySqlDataReader pois o mesmo não suporta múltiplas consultas em uma mesma conexão, então mudei do MySqlDataReader para o DataTable para popular a List.

Aquestão é, porque em todos os exemplos na net se recomenda usar o DataReader para popular uma list, Quais os problemas em usar o DataTable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As abordagens no uso **DataReader** e **DataAdapter** (que é o que você deve estar usando para popular o seu **DataTable**) são as seguintes:

#### DataReader:

- Obtém-se uma conexão com o banco de dados
- Envia o comando SQL
- O controle retorna imediamente para o código, tão logo haja registros a processar ou tão logo o banco de dados informe que não há nenhum registro
- O código começa a processar os registros imediamente - eventualmente o banco de dados sequer terminou de encontrar todos os registros ainda.
- Os registros já processados ficam imediatamente disponíveis para serem liberados da memória.
- Uma vez terminado o processamento de todos os registros, a conexão é liberada.

#### DataAdapter:

- Obtém-se uma conexão com o banco de dados
- Envia o comando SQL
- Quando todos os registros tiverem sido selecionados e entregues pelo banco de dados, o controle retorna para o seu código.
- A conexão com o banco é liberada.
- Os registros estão todos na memória, e agora você pode processá-los, desconectado do banco de dados.

#### Conclusão

Não existe problema em nenhuma das abordagens.

A primeira é mais adequada para o processamento de grande volume de registros pois você ganha tempo (começa a processar enquanto o banco de dados ainda está selecionando e entregando os registros) e demanda menos memória pois os registros não precisam ser carregados todos ao mesmo tempo antes de serem processados.

A segunda é mais adequada para o processamento de volume menor de registros e para quando há a intenção de editar os registros e mandar as atualizações para o banco.

Se você está preenchendo um *list view*, deve estar lidando com um volume relativamente pequeno de registros então a abordagem do **DataAdapter** mais **DataTable** parece ser mais a adequada pois é a mais simples de se implementar e inclusive este é o padrão do ADO.Net: trabalhar desconectado.

#### Observação: como se processa grande volume de dados utilizando-se diversos DataReaders

Há servidores de banco de dados que permitem múltiplos resultsets em uma mesma conexão, de modo que você não teria este erro.

No **Oracle** este recurso está ativado por padrão.

No **MS SQL Server**, este recurso se chama **MARS** e pode ser habilitado através da string de conexão. Você só teria exceção se tentasse abrir uma transação enquanto um dos resultsets estiver pendente (ainda não tiver terminado de ler todos os registros) na mesma conexão.

Quando o banco de dados não permite mais de um resultset na mesma conexão, uma abordagem comum é abrir uma nova conexão para cada resultset (no caso, para cada DataReader sendo processado em paralelo). Esta solução pode ter um custo mais alto pois cada conexão com o banco de dados tem um custo significativo.

Comment: Eu preencho um List que será exibido em um DataGridView com no máximo 20.000 registros. A sua explicação deixou claro do porque usar o DataReader (o que pretendo fazer quando o BD for SQL Server), mas nesta aplicação com MySQL usarei o DataAdapter com o DataTable. Obrigado.